How to use .zIndex() in LazyVGrid?
I have 4 custom tile views inside a 2x2 LazyVGrid. The tiles expand and contract when tapped.
I use .zIndex() to bring an expanded tile to the front of the Z-plane so that it isn't blocked by the other 3 tiles.
However, some of my tiles are still being blocked by the others.
I have attached pictures of the issue. You can see that when the bottom right tile expands it correctly moves to the front of the other 3 tiles. But the top left, top right, and bottom left tiles all have 3, 2, or 1 other tiles blocking them.
All tiles unexpanded
Top left tile expanded
Top right tile expanded
Bottom left tile expanded
Bottom right tile expanded
Here is my code:
struct SetupView: View {
    @State private var expandedTile: Int? = nil
    let columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self) { index in
                        OperationTileView(
                            tileSize: geometry.size.width / 2 ,
                            tileIndex: index,
                            alignment: alignment(for: index),
                            expandedTile: $expandedTile
                        )
                        .zIndex(expandedTile == index ? 1 : 0)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Determines the alignment for a given tile index
    private func alignment(for index: Int) -> Alignment {
        switch index {
        case 0: return .topLeading
        case 1: return .topTrailing
        case 2: return .bottomLeading
        case 3: return .bottomTrailing
        default: fatalError("Invalid index")
        }
    }
}


struct OperationTileView: View {

    let tileSize: CGFloat
    let tileIndex: Int
    let alignment: Alignment
    @Binding var expandedTile: Int?
    
    private var isExpanded: Bool {
        expandedTile == tileIndex
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .fill(isExpanded ? Color.blue: Color.gray)
                .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.1), radius: 10, x: 0, y: 5)
        }
        .frame(width: isExpanded ? tileSize * 2 : tileSize, height: isExpanded ? tileSize * 2 : tileSize, alignment: alignment)
        .offset(isExpanded ? offset(for: alignment) : .zero)
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.4, dampingFraction: 0.7), value: isExpanded)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                expandedTile = isExpanded ? nil : tileIndex
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func offset(for alignment: Alignment) -> CGSize {
        switch alignment {
            case .topLeading: return CGSize(width: tileSize/2, height: tileSize/2)
            case .topTrailing: return CGSize(width: -(tileSize/2), height: tileSize/2)
            case .bottomLeading: return CGSize(width: tileSize/2, height: -(tileSize/2))
            case .bottomTrailing: return CGSize(width: -(tileSize/2), height: -(tileSize/2))
            default: return .zero
        }
    }
}



This is because LazyVGrid is a bit too lazy and doesn't update the z indices. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/78607443/5133585 for example. Do you actually need a LazyVGrid? It's not in a ScrollView so it won't actually have any performance benefits. How about a regular Grid instead?

@Sweeper I tried Grid and it works properly now thank you. Oddly enough I initially searched Grid in the XCode Library and the only things that came up were LazyVGrid and LazyHGrid

Answering my own question because Sweeper's comment gave me the solution.
Per his/her explanation LazyVGrid did not update the Z indices. Switched to using Grid and the expanded tiles now come to the front of the Z plane correctly.
